# Reading computed properties in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I'm trying to figure out what the best way of achieving this is. I might be thinking about it in the wrong way, but this is what I "want" to achieve:

```
<div>
    {{#if selection}}
        <div>There is a selection in Component!</div>
    {{/if}}
    <Component />
</div>
```

where `selection` is a computed property in `Component` that I want to consume in the outer scope. Is there any way of referencing the property of the component instance?

For example:

```
<div>
    {{#if foo.selection}}
        <div>There is a selection in Component!</div>
    {{/if}}
    <Component id="foo" />
</div>
```

Or is this the wrong way of thinking about it. The only other way I can think of is to use events instead.

```
<div>
    {{#if selection}}
        <div>There is a selection in Component!</div>
    {{/if}}
    <Component on-selection="select" />
</div>
```

But that's not as elegant since it requireextra code:

```
ractive.on("selection", function(e) { this.set("selection", ...); });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in version `0.8` you *can* directly map the event to the data value (see http://jsfiddle.net/0zubyyov/) which nicely decouples the component internals from the parent:

template:

```
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    {{#if selected}}selected!{{/if}}
    <component on-select='set("selected", $1)'/>
</script>

<script id='component' type='text/ractive'>
    <input type='checkbox' on-change='fire("select", event.node.checked)'>
</script>
```

javascript:

```
Ractive.components.component = Ractive.extend({
    template: '#component',
    data: { selected: false }
});

var r = new Ractive({
    el: document.body,
    template: '#template'
});
```

Using `0.7` you might consider passing in a value to the component that's kept up to date (see http://jsfiddle.net/gr6d7vs8/). I was more explicit in this one about handling a *computed* property:

```
<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    {{#if selected}} selected! {{/if}}
    <component selected='{{selected}}'/>
</script>

<script id='component' type='text/ractive'>
    <input type='checkbox' checked='{{checked}}'>
</script>
```

javascript:

```
Ractive.components.component = Ractive.extend({
    template: '#component',
    data: { checked: false, allowed: true },
    computed: {
        isChecked () {
            return this.get('checked') && this.get('allowed')
        }
    },
    oninit(){
        this.observe('isChecked', isChecked => {
            this.set('selected', isChecked);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess I'm using a similar solution right now as to what you described for 0.7. I also use an observer - but I placed it in the parent rather than the component (by fetching a reference to the component through ``findComponent``) - which I think is a bit nicer as I don't have to have two properties in the component (one computed and one not).